# Remove Alpha characters from Suffix of string Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

How can I remove an alpha suffix from a line?
I.e.

AA12412BB
Should return
AA12412

basically looking right to left removing any characters after the last numeric character

Answer (score 5):

Try this: `$line =~ s/\D+\z//;`

Comment: I gave this a +1, but it pays to bear in mind that `\z` matches end-of-string, so it won't work if the string has a trailing `\n` (which would occur e.g. if you're reading lines of text from a file and not `chomp`ing them).

Comment: Sure it will! You’re telling me you think a newline is a `\d` code point, do you?  Since it isn’t `\d`, then it must be `\D`. Qᴇᴅ.

Comment: @tchrist: True, it will match and strip the `\n`, but I would not call that "working" -- if we are dealing with `\n`-terminated strings, they should remain `\n`-terminated, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 4):

If the string is in `$_`:

```
s/\D+?$//;
```

**[EDIT]:** Non-greedy matching (the `+?`) should be used if the line might end with `\n`, to avoid stripping this character (thanks to DanD for pointing this out).  This works because `$` will match either end-of-string, or immediately before a `\n` at end-of-string.

When working with lines of text, it's generally a good idea to first strip off any trailing `\n` by calling `chomp()`, then do whatever work is needed, and finally append a `\n` when the line is written out.  This simplifies handling suffixes and computing the length of the line, and is useful enough that perl provides the `-l` option to automate the process for one-liners.  In this case, the simpler `s/\D+$//;` can be used:

```
perl -lpe "s/\D+$//" < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of removing the newline at the end of each line with this? \n is matched by \D so presumably if you placed this in a while block that went through every line in the file, it would remove the \n as well? Or have i got this wrong?

Comment: @DanD: You're quite right, I'll update.  I would normally assume the line has been `chomp`ed before doing anything with it, but it pays to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str =~ s/(?<=\d)\D+//;
```

You might want to throw a `\b` in there if there are multiple targets in the line:

```
$str =~ s/(?<=\d)\D+\b//;
```

If you only want to affect the last match in a line, you can use $ instead:

```
$str =~ s/(?<=\d)\D+$//;
```

Comment: This will turn `12ABC345` into `12345`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: His original requirement didn't say that type of input was a possibility, or pose any rules for handling it. It was open to interpretation, so I offered the simplest pattern. However, I was already editing to suggest taking it into account. Please see edit.

Comment: He didn't say it *wasn't* a possibility either.  You can't assume that non-digits will never appear in the middle of a line, just because they didn't in his one example.  Also, don't know why you suggested `\b` -- maybe there are other items on the line that he doesn't want trailing non-digits stripped from.  Also, "after the last numeric character" in the OP's post implies there is at least one digit, so `(?<\d)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I think we're both making assumptions about what his input and output are supposed to be, but neither of us knows for sure. I suggested the `\b` because I thought he might have input like `ab123c de45ff`. It's an assumption, sure, but I don't think we can *avoid* assumptions with the question the way it is. You've assumed an end-of-line, for example, so yours would only remove `ff` from the above. What if the input is `abc`? Mine would be a non-match; yours wouldn't. Which is right? If he gave samples it would be clearer, but for now I think both yours and mine are correct.

Comment: The question title says "suffix of string", and the body says "suffix from a line".  So I haven't "assumed" an end-of-line -- it's right there in the question.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The question still seems very vague to me. You've still assumed a definite match, so your pattern would reduce `abc` to an empty string. I'm not even saying that's wrong, only that the question is unclear. However, I've added a third pattern and explanation to take your point into account, so the poster can choose whichever works for him.

Comment: It is badly worded (e.g. starts out "alpha", finishes up "non-numeric").  I grant you that my interpretation of "after the last numeric character" as meaning that there will always be at least 1 digit is not as conservative as it could be, so I think your `(?<=\d)` is justifiable, but I think there's no ambiguity surrounding the fact that he asked for a match only on the suffix of the line/string.

Comment: Alphabetic code points are `\p{Alphabetic}`.  Numeric code points are `\p{Number}`.

Answer (score -1):

`s/[A-Za-z]{2}$//;`

Or if you want a one-liner, type this in at the DOS prompt:

`perl -pe "s/[A-Za-z]{2}$//" <a.txt >b.txt`

This removes 2 alphabetic characters from the end of every line in a.txt and saves the new data to b.txt

If the line doesn't end in 2 alphabetic characters then the line is not modified. If b.txt doesn't exist already then it is created. If b.txt does exist then any old contents in b.txt is destroyed.
a.txt and b.txt need to be in the directory that you are in when you type the one-liner e.g. if you are in C:\users when you type in the one-liner than a.txt and b.txt need to also be in C:\users

Comment: Why assume the suffix will be exactly 2 characters?  His example was just *an example* -- he explicitly says, "basically looking right to left removing any characters after the last numeric character".  And why do you think a.txt and b.txt need to be in C:\?  Ever heard of `cd`?

Comment: yeah that's true - after posting i was thinking that your answer seems to fit the OPs needs better because it will be maximal. If you change the directory to like C:\users with cd\users then will that make any difference to what the one-liner does?

Comment: ah so the one-liner works anywhere - that's good - i need to change my post a bit

Comment: That does not “remove two alphabetic characters”; it removes two code points that each must be a letter between A and Z in upper or lower case, but not case insensitively.